# How to input and output values in array [][,] and [,][] (mix of jagged array and multidimensional array)

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I am trying to improve my code on how to find items in my multidimensional array, because I want to avoid possible future performance issues when I increase the data volume.  I am a newbie to programming, so there are lots of stuff I do not know.  I have been searching a lot around topics multidimensional array, jagged arrays, sorting.  I think I need to use jagged array because I need to sort in order to locate third largest and 6.largest number.  But I realize that I have to ask for some assistance on examples or link to more information because I am having problems making progress in defining my jagged array.  I will try to isolate each issue because I get stuck on things I believe might be easy for people that are more familiar with arrays than me.  It should be possible to mix jagged and multidimensional arrays according to [jagged-arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Here is example of [][] which is working

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace SortJaggedArray
{
class host
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[][] arr = new int[2][];
        arr[0] = new int[3] {1,5,3};
        arr[1] = new int[4] {4,2,8,6};

        // Write out a header for the output.
        Console.WriteLine("Array - Unsorted\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
             System.Console.WriteLine("Outer array " + i);

             for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
             {
                  System.Console.Write(arr[i][j] + " ");
             }
             System.Console.WriteLine(" ");
             System.Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}

//Output:
//Outer array 0
//1 5 3

//Outer array 1
//4 2 8 6
```

Here is my example of [][,] where the input is working, but I struggle with how to write the output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace SortJaggedArray
{
    class host
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][,] arr = new int[2][,]
            {
                new int[,] { { 1, 3 }, { 5, 2 }, { 3, 9 } },
                new int[,] { { 4, 1 }, { 2, 7 }, { 8, 5 }, { 6, 3 } }
            };
            // Write out a header for the output.
            Console.WriteLine("Array - Unsorted\n");

            foreach (int i in arr)
                Console.WriteLine(i);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

Wanted output:
Nr 0: 
1, 3
5, 2
3, 9

Nr 1:
4, 1
2, 7
8, 5
6, 3
```

Question 1: 
How to write the WriteLine / for / foreach in order to see the content of the jagged array [][,] ?

Question 2: 
I want to change this into [,][] but then I get problems in how to input/output data in such jagged array. How to input data?  How to Writeline / for / forearch to see the content of jagged array [,][] ?

Comment: This is almost always a sign of a missing class, where you're ***much*** better off creating a new class type and putting the instances in a list.

Comment: Joel is correct; it is almost always the wrong thing to do, to mix ragged and multidimensional rectangular arrays.  A much better idea is to clearly describe the semantics of the data you are manipulating in one or more generic classes, and then combine them. For more thoughts on why it is confusing to do what you're doing, see my 2009 article on the subject: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over every dimension:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++){
    Console.WriteLine($"Nr {i}:");
    for(int j=0;j<arr[i].GetLength(0);j++){
        for(int k=0;k<arr[i].GetLength(1);k++){
            Console.Write($"{arr[i][j,k]} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Outputs:

```
Nr 0:
1 3 
5 2 
3 9 

Nr 1:
4 1 
2 7 
8 5 
6 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Magnetron.  That solved my issue!  Your input on [][,] helped me also to solve the same thing for [,][]

Answer (score 0):

```
package array;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class multiDimensionalArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j;
        int values[][]=new int [3][3];
        System.out.println("Enter array values");
        for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
                values[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                }
        }
            System.out.println("Entered values are:  \t");
            for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
                for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
                    System.out.print("\t"+values[i][j]);
        }
                System.out.print("\n"); 
        
        }
    
            }
            
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In case other readers have the same question, I want to add code example on how Magnetron's example also helped me to solve the same issue for array [,][]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace SortJaggedArray
{
    class host
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,][] arr = new int[2,3][];
            arr[0,0] = new int[3] { 1, 5, 3 };
            arr[0,1] = new int[4] { 4, 2, 8, 6 };
            arr[0,2] = new int[2] { 2, 8 };
            arr[1,0] = new int[2] { 7, 5 };
            arr[1,1] = new int[5] { 8, 7, 5, 9, 2 };
            arr[1,2] = new int[2] { 1, 4};

            // Write out a header for the output.
            Console.WriteLine("Array - Unsorted\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Nr {i}:");
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < arr[i,j].Length; k++)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"{arr[i,j][k]} ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

//Output:
//Nr 0:
//1 5 3
//4 2 8 6
//2 8

//Nr 1:
//7 5
//8 7 5 9 2
//1 4
```